# Can NServiceBus Send to multiple endpoints?

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus, soa

Can NSB Send be mapped to multiple endpoints and received by multiple handlers? Or is it mostly a 1 - 1 operation?

Comment: Typically one would not need to do so.  As Adam Fyles has mentioned only events (through Publish) usually end up at multiple endpoints.  Your example *is*, however, something I've seen happening in a Message Broker environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is done via .Publish().  Certainly you can perform multiple .Send() with different addresses.  Where the addresses come from is up to you.  You can provide another set of configuration or override the configuration for the mappings.

Comment: Can you have a DTO/class be mapped into 2 different endpoints? eg. xxx dto goes to both abc@edf.com and also abc@qwe.com?

Comment: I just looked at the code and the message type is the key, so you cannot.  I would take another look at publishing.

Comment: @Alwyn can you explain why you'd want both endpoints to handle the same command?

Comment: @UdiDahan I was thinking of a 1-way publish, but somehow with less coupling in that the publisher in this case know of the target endpoints but not access to their subscription storage.

Comment: Can you describe the logical responsibilities you're envisioning? I can't seem to understand the scenario.